# RadioButtonFor remove default checked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this property in my view model:

```
public bool IsObligatory { get; set; }
```

and it should be filled by user in post method. The problem is that I get default value checked for second radio button. How to remove it? Even if I set IsObligatory property in my model as optional second radio button stays checked by default.

My model classes related to this problem:

```
public class Subject
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Semester { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<SubjectCourse> Courses { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<SubjectCourse> Subjects { get; set; }
}
public class SubjectCourse
{
   public int SubjectCourseID { get; set; }
   public int SubjectID { get; set; }
   public int CourseID { get; set; }
   public bool? IsObligatory { get; set; }

   public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
   public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

My view model:

```
public class SubjectVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<SelectedCourseVM> SelectedCourses { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class SelectedCourseVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsObligatory { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Part of my view:

```
<div class="form-group adding collapsable-courses">
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SelectedCourses.Count; i++)
   {
      <div class="panel-group" id="@Html.Id(@Model.SelectedCourses[i].Title)">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#@Html.Id(@Model.SelectedCourses[i].Title)" href="#@Model.SelectedCourses[i].ID">
                     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedCourses[i].ID)
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SelectedCourses[i].Selected, new { @class = "checkbox-inline" })
                     <label class="course-label">@Model.SelectedCourses[i].Title</label>
                  </a>
               </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="@Model.SelectedCourses[i].ID" class="panel-collapse collapse in courses-to-collapse" toggle="false">
               <div class="panel-body">
                   <div class="isobligatory-radios">
                       <label class="radio-inline">
                           @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectedCourses[i].IsObligatory, true)
                           Obavezan predmet
                       </label>
                       <label class="radio-inline">
                           @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectedCourses[i].IsObligatory, false)
                           Izborni predmet
                       </label>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to have neither radio buttons selected when you first display the view?

Comment: Then `IsObligatory` needs to be `bool?` as ataravati has indicated below (and the value of `IsObligatory` must be `null`). If that's not working, show how you are creating the loop.

Comment: Your code works fine (have already tested this). If `IsObligatory` typeof `bool?` and the value is `null`, then both neither radio button will be selected. But you would have a problem anyway because if you did not select a button from the first group, the collection would be `null` when you post back, so its not really clear why your wanting to do this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I don't see that as a problem. She can use a `RequiredAttribute` in the view model to make sure the property always has a value in post back.

Comment: @ataravati. The controls are generated in a loop. If no radio button is selected for the first item, but something is selected for the second item then nothing will post back for `SelectedCourses[0].IsObligatory` but a value will be posted for `SelectedCourses[1].IsObligatory`. The `DefaultModelBinder` required indexers start at zero and be consecutive so the whole collection will be `null` (unless a special hidden input is added for an `.Index` property)

Comment: I believe you :D but it's not working here for some reason. @StephenMuecke, in my case if I don't select button from first group, radio buttons from second group are not important (null, true, false, whatever). Sorry for late response. And I edited question.

Comment: Why are you setting `new {@checked = "unchecked"}` on both radio buttons? (`checked` or `checked="checked"` or `checked="true"` or `checked="unchecked"` or `checked="any-value"` all set the checkbox to checked). And `checked="checked"` is invalid anyway.

Comment: I was just trying to uncheck radio buttons by default, and forgot to delete that new {@checked = "unchecked"}. But when I remove it nothing changes.

Comment: If your view is based on your view model where `IsObligatory` which is `bool` (not nullable `bool`) then of course one of the radio buttons will be selected. The `IsObligatory` is `true`, it will be the first one, otherwise it will be the second one. That's how model binding works - it binds to the value of your property. If you want a null option, make it `bool?` as I noted in my second comment (but you need a 3rd radio button for the `null` option or binding of the collection will fail)

Comment: Hhh, I forgot to change there to bool?. too. Ok, I will keep that in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because your `IsObligatory` property is of type `bool`, so it can only either be true or false (default value is false). If you change the type to `bool?` (nullable), then the default value will be null, and neither of the radio buttons will be selected.

```
public bool? IsObligatory { get; set; }
```

Comment: I thought like that, but as I said even if I put IsObligatory to optional (bool?) second radio button is selected by default.

Comment: That's not possible. Please update the code in your question. What do you have in your controller? How do you create your view model?